# Django ORM object

Tags: django, python-3.x

I used Django ORM.

And when I type

`from app.models import Weather`

`Weather.objects.all()`

It printed:

```
DEBUG 2017-06-11 09:43:44,051 utils 12912 384 (0.083) SELECT `weather`.`id`, `weather`.`time`, `weather`.`tpr`, `weather`.`wet`, `weather`.`uv` FROM `weather` LIMIT 21; args=()
```

And when I type `print(Weather.objects.all())`

It printed:

```
[<Weather: Weather object>, <Weather: Weather object>, <Weather: Weather object>, <Weather: Weather object>, <Weather: Weather object>, <Weather: Weather object>, <Weather: Weather object>, <Weather: Weather object>, <Weather: Weather obj]
```

And then I added def unicode(self) in the Weather class

here is the following code:

```
class Weather(models.Model):
    tpr = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    wet = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    ur = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    li = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    observe_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tpr
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.wet
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.uv
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.li
```

But the result wasn't change.

How can I do next?

Comment: why you define 4 unicode methods? if you are using python 3 then define def __str__(self):

Comment: thank, I think I can `def __str__(self):    return self.tpr,self.wet,self.uv,self.li`

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self): 
    return "{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(self.tpr, self.wet, self.ur, self.li)
```